# goto was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, goto

```
@echo off
color 0a
title Horror Game
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Welcome to the game
echo If you get scared
echo Feel free to leave
echo.
echo.
echo You are in a dark room.
echo It is cold.
echo All you hear is a scratching sound
echo near your feet.
echo What do you do?
echo.
echo.
echo 1.) Feel around you
echo 2.) Listen for anything else
set/p input = Command?
if %input% == "1" goto Feel
if %input% == "2" goto Listen
echo.
echo.
:Feel
echo You feel around and hear a growl.
echo As you realize the scratching was
echo on your leg.
echo. 
echo You remember nothing else.
pause
end
```

I am trying to make a text based game for cmd and whenever i try to enter a response is instantly closes and i can barely read out "goto was unexpected at this time"

Answer (score 7):

You did not form your tests correctly.  You need to enclose the variable in double-quotes:

```
if "%input%" == "1" goto Feel
if "%input%" == "2" goto Listen
```

Note that you need an extra condition after these to deal with the possibility that they didn't enter 1 or 2.

You should consider using the `choice` command instead of `set /p`.  Type `choice /?` from the command prompt.

In future, run your script from the command prompt if you're having trouble with premature termination.  That way the window won't close on you and you'll have plenty of time to read the error.

You can run a command prompt quickly by pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, typing `cmd` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: +1 Using this method you can type two word answers and also no answer, without any error occurring.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the space between `input` and `=` in the `set` command, otherwise you're actually setting a variable with the name `input`　 (with a space at the end). This works as expected:

```
echo 1.) Feel around you
echo 2.) Listen for anything else
set/p input=Command?
if %input% == "1" goto Feel
if %input% == "2" goto Listen
echo.
echo.
:Feel
echo You feel around and hear a growl.
echo As you realize the scratching was
echo on your leg.
echo. 
echo You remember nothing else.
```

However, without quotation marks around `%input%` this will produce the `unexpected goto` error if the user enters an input with a space in it. paddy's suggestion to use the choice command is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that when you are in a Windows File Explorer window, you can type "cmd" into the File Explorer address bar, push , and this will produce the Command Prompt with the prompt path already navigated to the folder currently being viewed in the File Explorer window (presumably the folder with your batch file).  Then you can type the name of your batch file to run it.  As someone previously mentioned, you can more easily see your error codes this way instead of the window closing out, but this method (as opposed to using the Windows key - R) gives you a better way to get to the command prompt since you won't have to fuss with any "CD" commands to get to the folder you want.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33428997)